# I get the following error on running my script : [error] NameError ( global name 'FNC_POS_GCH_TestSuite' is not defined )

Tags: python, nameerror

I need to create a test suite consisting of suites. I have written the following code to create a suite and getting the name error `global name is not defined`.

```
# IMPORTS, SETTINGS AND VARIABLES - do not edit
commonPath = "C:\\SikuliX\\AutomatedTest\\COMMON"
scriptPath1 = "C:\\SikuliX\\AutomatedTest\\TESTSCRIPTS\\GCH_GENERAL_CREDIT_HANDLING\\FNC_POS_GCH_GENERAL_CREDIT_HANDLING"
scriptPath2 ="C:\\SikuliX\\AutomatedTest\\TESTSCRIPTS\\DM_DEMO_MODE\\FNC_POS_DM_DEMO_MODE"
scriptPath3 ="C:\\SikuliX\\AutomatedTest\\TESTSCRIPTS\\SS_SESSION_START\\FNC_POS_SS_SESSION_START"
from sikuli import *
import sys
if not commonPath in sys.path: sys.path.append(commonPath)
if not scriptPath1 in sys.path: sys.path.append(scriptPath1)
if not scriptPath2 in sys.path: sys.path.append(scriptPath2)
if not scriptPath3 in sys.path: sys.path.append(scriptPath3)
import os
import datetime
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner
from FNC_POS_GCH_TestSuite import *
from FNC_POS_DM_Start_DemoMode_TestSuite import *
from FNC_POS_SS_TestSuite import *

def suite():
    #masterSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
    #masterSuite.addTests(FNC_POS_GCH_TestSuite.suite())
    #masterSuite.addTests(FNC_POS_DM_Start_DemoMode_TestSuite.suite())
    #masterSuite.addTests(FNC_POS_SS_TestSuite.suite())
    s1 = FNC_POS_GCH_TestSuite.suite()
    s2 = FNC_POS_DM_Start_DemoMode_TestSuite.suite()
    masterSuite = unittest.TestSuite([s1, s2])
    return masterSuite

def main():
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    startDate = str(today)
    dir = "C:/Reports/"
    fileList = os.listdir(dir)
    [ os.remove(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,fileName))) for fileName in fileList ]
    filename = startDate+"_TESTSUITE_MasterSuite_Report.html"
    print filename
    fp = file(os.path.join(dir, filename), "wb")
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream = fp, verbosity=2)
    result = runner.run(suite())
    fp.close()
    count = str(result.success_count+result.failure_count+result.error_count),
    Pass = str(result.success_count),
    fail = str(result.failure_count),
    error = str(result.error_count),
    text_file = open(dir+"/Summary.txt", "a")
    text_file.write("Summary of the Scripts: "+filename + "\n")
    text_file.write("Total Scripts executed : %s" % count + "\n")
    text_file.write("Scripts  Passed        : %s" % Pass + "\n")
    text_file.write("Scripts  Failed        : %s" % fail + "\n" )
    text_file.write("Scripts  Error         : %s" % error + "\n" )
    text_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

I would appreciate it if you could let me know where I am going wrong with the script.

Comment: It is exactly as the error says.  `FNC_POS_GCH_TestSuite` is not defined.  Where is this module coming from?

Comment: Anthony, the issue has been resolved .I had to modify the script in place of "from FNC_POS_GCH_TestSuite import *" had to change it to "import FNC_POS_GCH_TestSuite".the module FNC_POS_GCH_TestSuite is coming from the path scriptPath1 = "C:\\SikuliX\\AutomatedTest\\TESTSCRIPTS\\GCH_GENERAL_CREDIT_HANDLING\\FNC_POS_GCH_GENERAL_CREDIT_HANDLING